# Share to mail and messages

Tags: objective-c, macos, email, message

Where can I find any info about how to share image to `mail` or `messages`? Just like for example `preview` share function. Here is photos:

[image]
[image]

Is there any frameworks or something to achieve it easily, or there are some others methods?

Answer (score 1):

Use the new [share menu](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Controls/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000359-SW37). Note that this is a new feature in Mountain Lion.

> To create a Share menu in Interface Builder, select the appropriate
>   button. Then, in the Attributes pane of the inspector, specify
>   `NSImageNameShareTemplate` for the image. To create one using AppKit
>   programming interfaces, use `NSImageNameShareTemplate` to add an image
>   to a button
>   ([`NSButton`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButton_Class/Reference/Reference.html)).
>   If you create a Share button programmatically, in order for the Share
>   menu to behave as users expect, you need to set
>   `sendActionOn:NSLeftMouseDownMask`.